# Sections missing from Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio

I've just re-installed Visual Studio and noticed a change in Team Explorer.

In the changes section there used to be three sub sections titled `Included Changes`, `Excluded Changes` and `Untracked Files`.

These seem to have disappeared and I can't get them back.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Which version of VS?

Comment: Vs 2015. It's okay on another machine, just seems to be a problem on this machine

Comment: Looks like it has been changed for git repos. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909473/visual-studio-2015-update-2-team-explorer-missing-exclude)

Answer (score 0):

Hi went over the documentation and could not find any mention on how to do it.

The only thing i found is this - which i don't think match your question exactly, but still give it a try to see if its working or not. :

> When you click on `Detected Changes` in the Team Explorer pane, `Promote Candidate Changes` window opens.
>   This window allows you to select among detected changes and promote them to a source controlled item.
>
> In this `Promote Candidate Changes` window, you select a file (or multi select files with Shift), right-click on it and a context menu pops up which contains an `ignore this local item` option.
>   If you you click on it, selected files are excluded from source control.

Comment: Thanks but no dice I'm afraid. I don't seem to have these options. I'm using a GIT repository so maybe that's why?

Comment: This is the only thing i found. was searching for answer for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm out of options so guess I'll have to live with it